# React Testing Library - possible to render page in browser

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm testing a UI with the React Testing Library. Wondering if there is any way (including incorporating a separate package) to render the page being created by a test in my browser as I run the test. I'm basically trying to accomplish what happens with Ruby's Capybara gem's save_and_open_page function within my React tests. Is it possible?

Comment: I recommend looking at using something like cypress other than react-testing-library for doing this

Answer (score 4):

You can render a component in the browser by using the [testing playground](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#screenlogtestingplaygroundurl):

```
import { screen } from "@testing-library/react"

render(<MyComponent />)

// log entire document to testing-playground
screen.logTestingPlaygroundURL()
// log a single element
screen.logTestingPlaygroundURL(screen.getByText('test'))
```

Comment: seems to cut it off after a certain point, just like console.log(prettyDOM())... makes it tough to debug, guess you gotten drill in like the second example.